# Node-webkit reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node-webkit

So Im moving my files to node-webkit and Im using socket.io the problem is...

Testing on my localhost everything works fine but when I move it to node-webkit I get

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

These are my files:

Package.json

```
{
"name": "Editme",
"main": "index.html",
    "window": {
    "show": true,
    "position": "center",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500,
    "toolbar": false,
    "resizable": false
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OrbitMMO</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="game/game.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="game/canvasengine-1.3.2.all.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login">
            <input type="text" id="name" />
            <input type="password" id="password" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" />
        </div>
        <canvas id="canvas_game" width="600px" height="700px" >

        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Game.js

```
var documentLoaded = setInterval(function() {
if(document.readyState === "complete")
    {
        clearInterval(documentLoaded);
        startClient();
    }
}, 5);


function startClient()
{
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
}
```

On the same folder of my index.html I have a copy of the node-modules folder of my server.
So I dont really know why is it not working and it is on localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json should include all the modules itself. You can either edit the file manually, or re-install your npm modules, ending the with `--save` i.e.  `npm install socket.io --save`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, however I was using node require to load socket.io. My solution was to require [socket.io-client](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client) (the stand alone version from npm). Im not sure this will help you, but I thought I would post anyway..